# Calculate Gross Margin Using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Disclaimer: I am somewhat new to SQL.

I am working on a query that calculates percent gross margin for each item on an invoice.  I want to sum up the dollar amount gross margin of the items where the percent gross margin is 20% or below.

All of the required information is in one table called "INVOICES."  A sample of the table is in the image

[image]Our '401%' accounts are revenue accounts and our '500%' accounts are cost of goods accounts.

The query I am currently working with is:

```
SELECT SUM(-AMOUNT) /
  (SELECT SUM(-AMOUNT)
   FROM INVOICES
   WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '401%')
FROM INVOICES
WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '401%'
  OR GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '500%'
GROUP BY INVOICE_ID,
         ITEM_ID;
```

The problem with the query above is that it is giving me the item margin/company revenue instead of item margin/item revenue.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Please let me know if I am unclear about anything.

Comment: So, it seems for each "revenue" item there is a matching "cost" item in your list. Presumably the item_id can be used to match which cost goes with which revenue (at least given an invoice_ID) - that is, for any given invoice_ID there will be only one row for each distinct item_id for account 40100, and a matching row (with the same quantity) for the 50000 account? Gross margin, then, is (revenue - cost) / revenue? And when you say you want to sum up dollar amount, that means multiplied by the corresponding quantity for each item with a gross margin less than or equal to 20%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query creates a new set of rows, one for each item on each invoice, showing both the revenue and the cost. (I included the quantity, although it seems the "amount" shown in your table already takes quantity into account.) I changed the sign on revenue amount - if anything, costs should be shown as negative, you have them reversed in your setup.

```
select r.invoice_id, r.quantity, r.item_id, -r.amount as revenue, c.amount as cost
from   (select invoice_id, quantity, item_id, amount 
        from   invoices 
        where  gl_account_id like '401%') r
join   (select invoice_id, item_id, amount 
        from   invoices
        where  gl_account_id like '500%') c
    on  r.invoice_id = c.invoice_id
    and r.item_id    = c.item_id
;
```

This produces the following result:

```
INVOICE_ID   QUANTITY ITEM_ID       REVENUE       COST
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     42811          1 GLV-L              10          5
     42811          1 GLV-M              20         19
     42811          1 GLV-S              30         28

3 rows selected.
```

Now it is easy to add up the dollar amount of gross margin (defined as revenue minus cost) for the rows where the gross margin is less than or equal to 20%. Note that the last condition is equivalent to cost >= 0.8 * revenue; I wrote the condition this way. Ideally 20% should be an input - you can use a bind variable or some other mechanism to allow 20% to be a user input. (Then my 0.8 should be 1 - this value).

I used the query above as a subquery, in a "with" clause; if your Oracle version is old, this may not be available and you may need to rewrite the query to include this as a traditional subquery.

The result is itemized by invoice_id; if you want a grand total, simply omit the "group by" clause and the result will be a grand total over the entire table.

```
with amounts as (
      select r.invoice_id, r.quantity, r.item_id, -r.amount as revenue, c.amount as cost
      from   (select invoice_id, quantity, item_id, amount 
              from   invoices 
              where  gl_account_id like '401%') r
      join   (select invoice_id, item_id, amount 
              from   invoices
              where  gl_account_id like '500%') c
          on  r.invoice_id = c.invoice_id
          and r.item_id    = c.item_id
     )
select invoice_id, sum(revenue - cost) as gross_amt_for_low_margins
from   amounts
where  cost >= 0.8 * revenue
group by invoice_id
;
```

Result:

```
INVOICE_ID GROSS_AMT_FOR_LOW_MARGINS
---------- -------------------------
     42811                         3

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM( -AMOUNT ) /
  NULLIF( SUM( CASE WHEN GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '401%'
                 THEN -AMOUNT
                 ELSE 0
               END ), 0 )
FROM INVOICES
WHERE ( GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '401%'
     OR GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '500%' )
GROUP BY INVOICE_ID,
         ITEM_ID;
```

Comment: Where in this query do you filter out the items that have a gross margin greater than 20%?

Comment: I chose to solve it for the expected result mentioned at bottom of question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(-i.AMOUNT) / 
    (SELECT SUM(-s.AMOUNT) 
    FROM INVOICES s 
    WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '401%' 
        AND s.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID)
FROM INVOICES i
WHERE i.GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '401%'
  OR i.GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '500%'
GROUP BY i.INVOICE_ID,
         i.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: Where in this query do you filter out the items that have a gross margin greater than 20%?

Comment: @mathguy I assumed his was already resolving that, or did not need help with it.  I responded to the problem he described at the bottom of his question.